# Внесение начальных значений и результатов в dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите пожалуйста, надо внести начальные значения из textBox в колонки таблицы, после чего по формуле вычисляется результат и вносится в последнюю колонку. К примеру начальные значения А и B в первую и вторую колонки, а результат C в третью. Колонок всего 5: год, месяц, объем, цена, выручка. Количество строк соответствуют количеству месяцев, т.е. 12. Формула такова объем*цена=выручка. Прошу сильно заумно не загибать - я очень слаб в программировании.

Comment: @Korol_tref, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: А это и не учебное задание. У нас универ не работает в этом году. Так что правила я не нарушил.

Answer (score 1):

Класс формы

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly BindingList<Entity> _entities = new BindingList<Entity>(); 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _entities;
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _entities.Add(new Entity()
            {
                Year = Convert.ToUInt16(textBoxYear.Text),
                Month = Convert.ToUInt16(textBoxMonth.Text),
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPrice.Text),
                Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxVolume.Text),
                Revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxVolume.Text)
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Класс выручки

```
  namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public uint Year { get; set; }
        public uint Month { get; set; }
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Revenue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Если значения введены в столбик.

```
if (textBoxYear.Lines.Count()>1)
            {
                _entities.Add(new Entity()
                {
                    Year = Convert.ToUInt16(textBoxYear.Lines[0]),
                    Month = Convert.ToUInt16(textBoxYear.Lines[1]),
                    Price = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxYear.Lines[2]),
                    Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxYear.Lines[3]),
                    Revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxYear.Lines[3]) * Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxYear.Lines[2])
                });
            }
            else
            {
                _entities.Add(new Entity()
                {
                    Year = Convert.ToUInt16(textBoxYear.Text),
                    Month = Convert.ToUInt16(textBoxMonth.Text),
                    Price = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPrice.Text),
                    Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxVolume.Text),
                    Revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxVolume.Text)
                });
            }
```

Все это примитивно, нужно везде делать проверки, разнести по методам, в общем дерзайте.

Comment: А если textBox один общий? Цифры введены столбиком.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.